# PHP Add days to datetime based on form selection

Tags: php

I am trying to insert a datetime into my MySQL DB that adds a certain amount of time depending on what is selected from the form. For example, clicking the button on `2021-04-01 22:00:00` and selecting "1 day" would result in an entry in my DB of `2021-05-01 22:00:00`, "3 Days" `2021-07-01 22:00:00` etc...

Here is what I have so far but I can't get it to work. Can anyone point me in the best direction? I've trimmed down my code to make it more readable, i think it makes sense though.

```
<?php
// Include config file
require_once "config.php";
$expire = "";
$expire_err = "";
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
 
// Create a function to add + days to current datetime based on value selected one form and insert into DB column expire 
// 

$input_expire = trim($_POST["expire"]);

if ($input_expire = "1 Day" {

// add + 1 day
$expire_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$expire_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($expire_date . ' +1 day'));
$expire = $expire_date;
echo $expire_date;

} elseif ($input_expire = "3 Day" {

// add + 3 day
$expire_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$expire_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($expire_date . ' +3 day'));
$expire = $expire_date;
echo $expire_date;

} else ($input_expire = "5 Day" {
    
// add + 5 day
$expire_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$expire_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($expire_date . ' +5 day'));
$expire = $expire_date;
echo $expire_date;

}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

if(empty($expire_err)){
        $sql = ("INSERT INTO table (expire) VALUES ('$expire')");
        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $param_expire);
            // Set parameters
            $param_tags = $expire;
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                header("location: index.html");
                exit();
            } else{
                echo "Something went wrong";
            }
        }
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }
    mysqli_close($link);
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Create Message</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                   <div class="page-header">
                    <h2>Create Message</h2>
                    </div>
                    <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
                        <div <p style="width: 45%"; class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($expire_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                            <label>Message Expiry</label>
                            <select class="form-control" name="expire"><?php echo $expire; ?>
                                <option value=""></option>
                                <option value="1 Day">1 Day</option>
                                <option value="3 Days">3 Days</option>
                                <option value="5 Days">5 Days</option>
                                </select>
                              <span class="help-block"><?php echo $expire_err;?></span>
                           </div>
                           <br>
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
                        <a href="index.html" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</a>
                        <br>
                    </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>        
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: _but I can't get it to work._ which is the problem?

Comment: In all control `if ($input_expire = "1 Day" {` you forgot `)`, so  `if ($input_expire = "1 Day") {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have much problem in this code:

- You didn't close `)` in all `if`
- All `if` use `=` instead of `==` ([operators link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php))
- In the form you write value like "5 Days" or "3 Days" but you try to catch "5 Day"
- The last `if` you use `else` instead of `elseif`

Final Code:

```
<?php

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
 
// Create function to add + days to current datetime based on value select on form and insert into DB column expire 
// 

$input_expire = trim($_POST["expire"]);

if ($input_expire == "1") {
    
// add + 1 day
$expire_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$expire_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($expire_date . ' +1 day'));
$expire = $expire_date;

} elseif ($input_expire == "3") {

// add + 3 day
$expire_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$expire_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($expire_date . ' +3 day'));
$expire = $expire_date;

} elseif ($input_expire == "5") {
    
// add + 5 day
$expire_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$expire_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($expire_date . ' +5 day'));
$expire = $expire_date;

}

echo $expire;
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Create Message</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                   <div class="page-header">
                    <h2>Create Message</h2>
                    </div>
                    <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
                        <div <p style="width: 45%"; class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($expire_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                            <label>Message Expiry</label>
                            <select class="form-control" name="expire"><?php echo $expire; ?>
                                <option value=""></option>
                                <option value="1">1 Day</option>
                                <option value="3">3 Days</option>
                                <option value="5">5 Days</option>
                                </select>
                              <span class="help-block"><?php echo $expire_err;?></span>
                           </div>
                           <br>
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
                        <a href="index.html" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</a>
                        <br>
                    </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>        
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I deleted some parts of code that were not needed by the post and I changed the values ​​with simple numbers so you already know that you want to use the days

Comment: Thank you, sorry I rushed somewhat to post this question, I didnt want to post to much and confuse, I see where I have gone wrong missing off ) and not using the correct operator - thanks for helping

Comment: Way too much repeated code in the snippet.

Comment: I'm not here to revisit the code I just corrected the errors. If the OP wants an additional service, he can contact a paid programmer. (me too if he want :D) or he can go to [https://codereview.stackexchange.com/](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Even if you only give attention to the code that you changed, would you use that code in your own project? There is a great opportunity to share knowledge and be generous here.

Comment: In my own project no, OP need to learn the basic concept like operator. I think he need just praticte. For example, instead of using all those `if` it was enough to use simple  `$expire = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . ' +'.$_POST["expire"].' day'));` obviously having only used numbers as I did in my example

Answer (score 0):

On your journey toward programming greatness, I'd like to share some general best practices that you should adopt.

1. Don't Repeat Yourself -- when you see repeated patterns in your code, try to isolate the few differences that can be turned into variables then seek a technique to best use the variables. For example, your form and your submission handling code both need to be aware of the valid expiration options -- for this reason make a variable which both codes can leverage.
2. For security, stability, and consistency in your application, always use prepared statements when using variables as values in your sql. Use placeholders in your prepared statement and bind your variables to those placeholders -- otherwise you are failing to enjoy the benefits of prepared statements.
3. Use mysqli's object oriented syntax.  It is less verbose and IMO easier to read.
4. A `<select>` tag, unless you are grouping options, should only have `<option>` tags for children.  Don't try to squeeze any other text inside of the `<select>`.
5. When the text of an `<option>` is identical to its `value` attribute, don't bother declaring the `value` attribute.

Suggested and untested code:

```
$expiries = [
    1 => '1 day',
    3 => '3 days',
    5 => '5 days',
];
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST") {
    $input_expire = $_POST["expire"] ?? '';
    if (!isset($expiries[$input_expire])) {
        $error = 'Missing/Invalid submission data';
    } else{
        $expire_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("+{$input_expire} days"));
        $stmt = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO table (expire) VALUES (?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $expire_date);
        if (!$stmt->execute()) {
            $error = "Failed to save";
        } else{
            header("location: index.html");
            exit();
        }
    }
}

// ... further down the script ...

<select class="form-control" name="expire">
    <option></option>
    <?php
    foreach ($expiries as $value => $text) {
        printf('<option value="%s">%s</option>', $value, $text);
    }
    ?>
</select>
```